# What school of thought did the Jews of Khazaria (or Kuzari) follow?

Tags: minhag

Inspired by Kuzari studies, I came to wonder about the Jewish community in Khazaria (Kuzari) in the time of the Khazaria empire.

What "school of thought" did the Jews of Khazaria (or Kuzari) follow that time?
Did that school of thought have any major differences with other schools of thoughts (that time or today)? Provide some if possible.
If this is impossible to answer, what about trying to speculate:
If one collects the information about (some) Jewish "beliefs" which exists in the Kuzari and other reports, and then analyses it (it has to be interpreted correctly too though), one might draw a conclusion or pin point that the result given in the analyse is similar to sect X understanding or some schools of thought have inclined to similar understandings.

Comment: I would assume something close to the Bukharian Jews. The Khazars lived in the same area, just at a much earlier time. Some even speculate that the world's Ashkenazi Jews came from the Khazars but this idea is often used to disinherit Ashkenazim from Eretz Yisroel.